# generate random selection from list of items to repeat every time a function is called out

Tags: python-3.x

```
def open_box(num_items):
    print('Opening Loot Box:')
    random.randint(1,100)
    for num_items in range(100):
        if rarity <= 5:
            return ('Legendary')
        elif rarity <= 15:
            return ('Epic')
        elif rarity <= 50:
            return('Rare')
        elif rarity<=100:
            return('Common')
        break
    random.shuffle(item)
    append.rarity(box_item)
    print ('' 'of', num_items,'...', Rarity, 'item!')
    return box_item
```

I am trying to get this function to print out the rarity of an item but i keep on coming back with errors.

Comment: What is `rarity` and where is it defined? You should try to include enough code that people can reproduce your issue. If you are getting errors, you should include the error in the question too.

Comment: What is it you want the code to do? If you just want to print out a 'rarity' based on a random number, that's one thing, but looks like you want to be able to make a list of items with associated rarity values.

Comment: Yes i am trying to print out a list of 4 items, that are given 4 random rarities. however i change the code around so much that i forgot which is right and which is wrong. My main objective is to print out 4 rarity items for now and if so expend.